# Send out E-Mail to new active-sync users Exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, activesync

I would like to send a email to the user each time there is a new device that connects to Exchange Activesync informing him of the security policy. This is a requirement from HR as we force wipe after a certain number of password attempts. I am easily able to get the current list but cannot find for the life of me a "First Sync" or similar attribute.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this, I would recommend two approaches.  1) Send out the HR policy to all mailboxes (to cover compliance) and 2) setup quarantine approvals (http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2010/11/15/3411539.aspx) for all devices so that IT has to approve the new AS connection (and can therefore know to send out the policy again if necessary).